# How to customize Siebel Open UI?

Tags: javascript, html, css, siebel

I am learning siebel UI, trying to customize one form, but not able to find any physical renderer js file. How can i create custom physical renderer to customize UI?

Comment: please share what you have tried.. and what you want exatcly

Comment: At Stack Overflow we expect those who ask to formulate their questions with some thought. In the guide [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) some of the expectations are clearly outlined. In short, the effort you put into the quality of your question will enable us to provide an answer of a similar nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to edit one form applet you need a physical renderer, if you can't find a physical renderer always the Siebel standard is loaded (phyrenderer) that you are forbidden to modify.

The best way would be to overload the existing Physical Renderer of the Form Applet with your own custom PR.

You can create one easily with [Duncan Fords PR / PM generator](http://duncanford.github.io/prpm-code-generator/?prpm=PR&object=DesktopForm&name=BeautifulThing&userprops=&comments=Yes&logging=No). Then you need to administrate it as it is described in the [Oracle Siebel Bookshelf](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/config_open_ui/customizing23.html).

If everything worked well you should now see the console logs in your Web Development Console (F12) and see the